# ChromeDriver's executeAsyncScript doesn't trigger ScriptTimeoutException properly

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I wanted to implement script execution time handling, but stumbled upon this issue. If I design webdriver's script to execute in following manner, it successfully returns a variable, but it doesn't trigger ScriptTimeoutException as it should be. Any ideas why? I've adopted this script from [webdriver's javadoc](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) example

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
//---setting script timeout to 1ns to force ScriptTimeoutException
driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(1, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);

//this script works fine, ScriptTimeoutException is triggered
String script1 = "window.setTimeout(arguments[arguments.length - 1], 500);";

//this script is able to pass his return variable back to Java, but doesn't triggers ScriptTimeoutException
String script2 = "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];" +
        "var stringVar = 'abcd';" + 
        "callback(stringVar);";

while (true) {
    Instant beforeScript = Instant.now();
    //((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeAsyncScript(script1);
    String result = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeAsyncScript(script2);
    System.out.println(result + " " + Duration.between(beforeScript, Instant.now()).toMillis());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after searching for a while and [discussing](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2040) this with selenium\chromedriver developers, I've found that my script wasn't actually async script.

The proper async script that will throw ScriptTimeoutException would be something like this:

```
var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
var stringVar = 'abcd';
setTimeout(()=>callback(stringVar), 100);
```